# Doubly Linked List Quick-Sort C

Tags: c, quicksort, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to find a way to implement a doubly linked list along with a quicksort algorithm to sort the linked list. So far I'm only working on the list however I keep running into a "segmentation fault" error. Anyone able to help?

source code for node.c:

```
#include "node.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Function to swap the nodes.
void swap(struct mynode* one, struct mynode* two){
    struct mynode *result = one;
    one = two;
    two = result;
}

//Function to determine the final node in the list.
struct mynode *finalnode(struct mynode *root){
    while(root && root->next){
        root = root->next;
        }
    return root;
}

//Function to split the nodes.
struct mynode* partition(struct mynode* one, struct mynode *two){

    const int x = two->value;

    struct mynode *i = one->prev;
    struct mynode *j = 1;

    for(j; j != two; j = j->next){
        if(j->value <= x){
            i = (i == NULL) ? one : i->next;
            swap(i, two);
        }
    }

    i = (i == NULL) ? one : i->next;
    swap(i, two);
    return i;
}

//Function to print the list.

void printlist(struct mynode *node){
    while(node){
        printf("%i", node->value);
        printf(" <=> ");
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//Function to insert node.
void insert(struct mynode** node, int new_value){

    struct mynode* new_node = NULL;
    new_node->value = new_value;

    new_node->prev = NULL;
    new_node->next = (*node);

    if((*node) != NULL){
        (*node)->prev = new_node;
    }

    (*node) = new_node;

}
```

source code for node.h:

```
#ifndef NODE_H_
#define NODE_H_

struct mynode{
    int value;
    struct mynode *next;
    struct mynode *prev;
};

struct mynode quicksort(struct mynode*);
void printlist(struct mynode *node);

#endif
```

Source code for main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "node.h"

void insert(struct mynode** node, int new_value);
void printlist(struct mynode *node);

int main(void){

    struct mynode *test = NULL;

    insert(&test, 5);
    insert(&test, 10);
    insert(&test, 2);
    insert(&test, 4);

    printf("Linked list prior to sort: ");
    printlist(test);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Just FYI: linked-lists are not thought to be reordered, you'll better create a new ordered one than try sorting the original.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
    struct mynode* new_node = NULL;
    new_node->value = new_value;
```

will surely segfault. You need to allocate some memory first:

```
    struct mynode * new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
```